# Apple Store in Ankara or Turkey

Tags: turkey, shopping, ankara

I just arrived in Ankara today, and I decided to buy an iPod, I had been planning to buy one and this time I really needed one. I Googled "apple store ankara" and found [some place on Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/preview?client=safari&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&fb=1&gl=tr&cid=12698707687946668050&q=Apple+Ankara&ei=D4PqU6HGDpTD4QTSyoHQCg&ved=0CMsBEPwSMAs) which turned out to be a total nowhere. At this time, I have come to guess that Apple is not officially sold in Turkey. (EDIT: now I know that is a wrong guess).

Is there any authorized seller in Ankara for Apple? Locals seem to not even know what an iPod is. But I have seen them use an iPhone. Where can I buy Apple products in here?

Comment: There are no official Apple Retail stores in Ankara. By September it is presumed there will be two located in Istanbul http://www.tuaw.com/2014/08/04/a-second-apple-store-in-the-works-for-istanbul/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best source for authorized Apple retailers will be Apple itself. [Apple's Turkish website](https://locate.apple.com/tr/) links you to sales information in Turkish or English. A search for turns up listings and a map for dozens of authorized retailers within Ankara, and dozens more in nearby cities such as Kirikkale and Çankiri. Additionally, [Apple's Online Store](http://store.apple.com/tr) has been operating in Turkey since autumn 2013.

There is at this writing only one official Apple Store in Turkey, [in the Zorlu Center](https://www.apple.com/tr/retail/zorlucenter/) in Istanbul. According to the [ElmaDergisi blog](http://www.elmadergisi.com/akasya-avm-apple-store-insaati/), a second Istanbul store is under construction in the Akasya Shopping Center, to open autumn 2014. [An earlier post](http://www.elmadergisi.com/turkiyede-acilmasi-beklenen-apple-storelar-ile-ilgili-gelismeler/) in that blog stated that stores were planned for Ankara and İzmir in 2015, a rumor endlessly repeated elsewhere, but one still lacking an authoritative confirmation.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I had already done that and it would give me locations in Washington, US. But when I changed to the Turkish page, I found places in Ankara.

Answer (score 1):

Note that list on Apple's page seems outdated. f.i. ElectroWorld closed all their stores in Turkey but they are still listed on Apple's website.

In Ankara, you can pretty much find one of the authorized retailers in any shopping center/mall.
Either MediaMarkt, D&R, TeknoSA, Gold Computer or Bimeks. At least one of these operate on any  mall you pick. Though if you do not speak Turkish, i recommend D&R or MediaMarkt, you have higher chances of finding someone who speaks English.

If you can comment below about where you are staying or where you visit/go to during the day, i can direct you to nearest place you can find an iPod.